# PHP: Use of DateTime Relative Formats for times < or > current time

Tags: php, datetime

Does anybody know of an elegant way of using the PHP DateTime relative formats feature well for DateTime's that are not the current time?

Basically - I can create a new DateTime with a RelativeFormat from the current time very easily with

```
new DateTime('first monday of this week');
```

It would be incredibly useful to be able to do the same with other dates, so something like either:

```
new DateTime('first monday of 4 Jun 2022');  -> Should return  30 May 2022
```

or

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2022-06-4 12:00:00);
$time->modify('first monday of week') -> Should return 30 May 2022
```

I know that this could be done with a function that mangles the date with various permutations of strtotime() but if anybody knows of a PHP library or something built into Relative Formats that I haven't found in the documentation which could achieve it more gracefully I'd be very grateful for the pointer.

Comment: Please describe the problem you are having and what exactly do you consider "elegant". Are you looking for a different date library like Carbon or not sure how to achieve your desired results with the PHP relative dates?

Answer (score 4):

Your code works you are just missing "`... this ...`" in the first parameter of `->modify()` as you want it to be relative to the DateTime describing *that* week.

```php
<?php
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2022-06-4 12:00:00');
$time->modify('first monday of this week'); //-> Should return 30 May 2022
var_dump($time);

/*
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2022-05-30 00:00:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}
*/

echo $time->format('d M Y'); // 30 May 2022
```

---

Demo on 3v4l.org: https://3v4l.org/nNR7X

---

Alternatively for the exact values you provide you could have meant `->modify("last monday");` that also returns 30th of May for June 4th this year but it would give you the previous week if the input date is a Monday itself, e.g. June 6th this year.

Comment: Can be further simplified as `new DateTime('2022-06-04 last monday')` or 
`new DateTime('2022-06-04 first monday of this week')` depending on the desired context. https://3v4l.org/i0eJI

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this - for some reason 'first monday of this week' always reset the DateTime to the first monday of the current system time, regardless of what I had passed into the DateTime object on creation.  I had some logic issues with passing DateTime objects between functions though, and I did more code rework today to solve those - so this approach might work for me now.

Comment: @Deggy `"this"` should always be relative to the object's specified date or system time (now) if not specified  but the relative date can also vary between PHP versions https://3v4l.org/Kdr5Z since the first day of the week changed from Sunday to Monday in PHP [7.0.8](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-7.php#7.0.8) and [5.6.23](https://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php#5.6.23) leading to unexpected results.

Answer (score 1):

`strtotime` function is exactly what you are searching for.
It gets reference time as second argument.

viz. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtotime` and `date` functions:

```
$time = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2022-06-04 12:00:10');
var_dump(date('M j Y', strtotime('first monday of this week', $time->getTimestamp())));
```

output:

`string(11) "May 30 2022"`